# Intersection of two named vectors saved as new named vector in R

Tags: r, vector, intersection, named

I'd like to know if there's an easy way to find an intersection of two named vectors and output the result to a third, named vector.

In my case, I have the following two named vectors:

```
> test1
ATMG00010 ATMG00030 ATMG00040 ATMG00050 ATMG00060 ATMG00070 
  462       324       948       396       542       573 

> test2
ATMG00010 ATMG00040 ATMG00070 
    0         0         0
```

What is the elegant way to find the intersection of the two vectors based on names and then output the name, value pair of test1 into a new named vector, test3?

i.e.,

```
> test3
ATMG00010  ATMG00040 ATMG00070 
  462         948       573
```

In order for me to get on with my life, I found an intermediate solution that got the job done, but the result was not a named vector, just a numerical vector of values from matched names in test1.

```
matched <- which(names(test1) %in% names(test2))
test3 <- rep(NA, length(test2))
for (i in 1:length(matched)) { test3[i] <- c(test1[[matched[i]]]) }
```

This gives me the following result:

> test3
>       [1] 462 948 573

As I only know a little bit of python and pretty much nothing about R, the above code was learned through an all day immersion process. Is there a more straightforward way to do this ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you would like to return values of the `test1` object:

```
test3 <- test1[intersect(names(test1),names(test2))]
```

`intersect()` outputs a character string with the names shared between the two vectors. By wrapping the resulting string within the square brackets, we can return matching elements of any vector, in this case `test1`.

Comment: @Kvothe, you're welcome. I am happy to help. If one of the answers solved you problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry I forgot to accept the answer -- was my very first post here. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

test3 <- join(test1, test2)[, intersect(names(test1), names(test2))]
```

Comment: Thank you as well for your answer!

Comment: No problem!  That's what the board is for! :)